# Format date from "yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS" to human readable format using angular 2

Tags: angularjs

I have a JSON data in the below format and want to display the `startDateTime` in human readable format.

```
  var txns = {    
   "payeeAccNum": "12081031991",
   "startDateTime": "2018-11-13T20:47:47.866"
 }
```

I have done in the following way, but it always showing time as **12:00:00 AM** only. can any one help on this?

```
<span [innerHTML]="(txns.startDateTime | date:'d MMM yyyy h:mm:ss a')"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the date filter you can format your date/time to any format you need to:

> 'medium': equivalent to 'MMM d, y h:mm:ss a' for en_US locale (e.g. Sep 3, 2010 12:05:08 PM)
>
> 'short': equivalent to 'M/d/yy h:mm a' for en_US locale (e.g. 9/3/10
> 12:05 PM)
>
> 'fullDate': equivalent to 'EEEE, MMMM d, y' for en_US locale
> (e.g. Friday, September 3, 2010)
>
> 'shortDate': equivalent to 'M/d/yy' for en_US locale (e.g. 9/3/10)
>
> 'mediumTime': equivalent to 'h:mm:ss a' for en_US locale (e.g.
> 12:05:08 PM)
>
> 'shortTime': equivalent to 'h:mm a' for en_US locale
> (e.g. 12:05 PM)

*Now what format do you want your time to be displayed in?*

for **Medium** display, use:

```
<span [innerHTML]="(txns.startDateTime |  date:'medium')"></span>
```

and it's better if you use `[innerText]` in stead of HTML for span contents.

to get something like medium date without seconds use `'MMM d, y h:mm a'`

Dateoffset filter:

```
transform(value: any, format = 'MM/dd/yyyy'): string {
    let formattedDt: string;
    if (value) {
        if (DateUtil.DATE_TIMEZONE_REGEX.test(value)) {
            value = this.removeTimezone(value);
        }
        formattedDt = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(value), format);
    }
    return formattedDt;
}

private removeTimezone(value: any): string {
    const timezoneDashIndex = value.lastIndexOf('-');
    return value.slice(0, timezoneDashIndex);
}
```

Comment: I want to display the date and time in 'Medium' format. can you please help on this

Comment: I tried like this, (txns.startDateTime | date:'medium'), but still it showing time as 12:00:00 AM.

Comment: @vishnu , what is your desired output? medium will show date time like this: Sep 3, 2010 12:05:08 PM, so 12:00:00AM is fine, If you do not want seconds, use 'short'. for getting just time use 'shortTime'

Comment: I am getting the response from server is, '2018-11-13T20:47:47.866'. I want to show like Nov 13, 2018 08:47 PM

Comment: @vishnu, then you should use 'MMM d, y h:mm a' as your filter format. hope it helps. I have updated my answer for you to accept.

Comment: I have used like, txns.startDateTime | date:'MMM d, y h:mm a' but still i am getting Nov 13, 2018 12:00 AM it should display like, Nov 13, 2018 08:47PM

Comment: looks like you are running into formatting issue. date filter converts the value to local time automatically. You need to have a custom filter to just take date value and extract time as is from the date value and return to view in stead of adjusting the time. also it should be fixed in higher version of angular

Comment: Or another workaround is to do this:<td class="minimal-table_body-cell">{{match.interactionTs | dateOffset:'MM/dd/yyyy'}} {{match.interactionTs | dateOffset:'shortTime'}}</td> and your date offset could be as shown in answers

Answer (score 0):

consider using moment.js library for datatime conversions

visit momentjs.com

for your code this is the solution:

> var requiredDateFormat= moment(tsnx.startDateTime).format('MM-DD-YYYY')